Selenium grid requests time out, don't execute. Python Multiprocessing
I'm writing a webscraping program in Python 3.12 using Selenium and multiprocessing. I am setting up selenium grid using docker and using that to run multiple selenium instances in parallel. However, any requests made to the grid do not get executed, and time out after 5 minutes. Even if I simplify my function down to just get the source code of the page, it still does not execute. I have the "requestor" built into a class. Here is the base function I'm trying to run (after I've stripped out all the calculations to be done for the html).
def get_discounts(self) -> list:
        discounts = []

        driveroptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        driveroptions.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444', options=driveroptions,      keep_alive=False)
        driver.get(self.current_url)
        html = driver.page_source()
        driver.quit()
        return discounts

also for reference, here is my docker-compose file:
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome:4.21.0-20240517
    shm_size: 2gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=8

  
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:4.21.0-20240517
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"

I've tried running this headless and even limiting the SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS down to only a few (3 or 4), and it still doesn't work. I'm running this all from a Dell laptop with only 16gb of RAM, and running the VM for docker eats up some of it. Once I actually run the grid, it gets close to maxing out my RAM (goes up to 14.8gb usage). Still have no clue why this won't work.
Also, running this function outside of grid using just selenium works just fine.

Using your Docker Compose stack I was able to run the following test script locally:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driveroptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driveroptions.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444', options=driveroptions,      keep_alive=False)
driver.get("https://www.example.com")

print(driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h1').text)

driver.quit()

It printed the HTML source as expected and I could see the selenium-hub and Chrome containers logging consistently as the browser was launched. Screenshot below shows the Docker Compose logs (top panel) and output from the test script (lower panel).

Reading your question again I see that you mention that you are running Docker on a VM. Do you mean that you have your webscraping client running locally and it's accessing the Selenium grid remotely on the VM? If this is the case then I have two suggestions:

If memory on the VM is a concern then I suggest adding some swap space. This will make Selenium less performant (probably not noticeably so), but will mean that you don't run into memory constraints.
Ensure that you are able to access the VM via the exposed ports (4442, 4443 and 4444). Have you tried simply running the Docker Compose stack on the same machine as the webscraping client (your laptop) without involving a VM? This would be a good first step (and the one that I tried successfully). Once you are happy that this works then move it across to the VM.

Also, it would be useful to clarify your actual setup. Can you give some details about the VM?

To update, I was able to SOMEWHAT resolve my own issue, but still running into a hiccup. The issue was that the site I was attempting to access through selenium was blocking access because Chrome was being controlled remotely. I fixed this by adding the user-agent argument to the driver.

Now, when grid runs these selenium instances, half of them will execute and complete, and all new instances to begin execution, but the other half will just time out and not execute at all. Not sure what could be causing this

Hard to help without more context.
